# Building a list of objects with bs4 that end up empty

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm using `bs4` to attempt at printing out the following structure:

```
Talent Build Name Staggering Blow Build
Category Recommended 
Level 1 On The Prowl
Level 4 Hogger's Jogger's
Level 7 Seeing Red
Level 10 Shockwave
Level 13 Pummel
Level 16 Headbanger
Level 20 No Control
Talent Build Name Ez-Thro Dynamite Build
Category Situational
Level 1 ...
```

Specs below:
VS Code
Win 10
Python 3.12.1
BS4 Version: 4.12.3
requests Version: 2.31.0

Scraped Website: https://www.icy-veins.com/heroes/hogger-talents

bs4 resource: https://blog.logrocket.com/build-python-web-scraper-beautiful-soup/

Python below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

#heroname = input("Enter hero name:")


def fetch_talent_html():
    # make a request to the target website
    r = requests.get("https://www.icy-veins.com/heroes/hogger-talents")
    if r.status_code == 200:
        # if the request is successful return the HTML content
        return r.text
    else:
        # throw an exception if an error occurred
        raise Exception("an error occurred while fetching icyveins html")
    
def extract_talents_info(html):
    # Create a BeautifulSoup object to parse the HTML content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

   # talentdiv = soup.find(class_='heroes_builds')
   # print(talentdiv.prettify())
    heroes_builds_collection = soup.find(class_='heroes_builds')
    heroes_builds = heroes_builds_collection.find_all("heroes_build")[1:]
    print(heroes_builds)
    # iterate through our builds
    builds = []
    for builds in heroes_builds:  
        talent_collection = builds.find("div", {"class": "heroes_build_talents"})
    return builds
```

I ran the code in VSCode and was expecting to see the list of talent builds, levels, and abilities.

When I modify the heroes_builds variable I get an error later on saying there is no h3 tag, so I have a feeling there's love there. I'm just not there yet. Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue easily. Take a minute to check - How to create [mcve] Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few of different issues, so just focus on what should matter - Try to iterate the HTML tree like you would read the page as human and pick the information needed by using the correct selectors:

```
def extract_talents_info(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    builds = []
    for b in soup.select('.heroes_build'):
        builds.append({
            'build_name': b.h3.get_text(),
            'category': b.span.text.strip(),
            'talents': [
                {
                    'level':t.span.get_text(),
                    'ability': t.img.get('alt')
                } 
                for t in b.select('.heroes_build_talent_tier')
            ] 
        })

    return builds
```

Results into:

```
[{'build_name': 'Staggering Blow Build',
  'category': 'Recommended',
  'talents': [{'level': 'Level 1', 'ability': 'On The Prowl Icon'},
   {'level': 'Level 4', 'ability': "Hogger's Joggers Icon"},
   {'level': 'Level 7', 'ability': 'Seeing Red Icon'},
   {'level': 'Level 10', 'ability': 'Shockwave Icon'},
   {'level': 'Level 13', 'ability': 'Pummel Icon'},
   {'level': 'Level 16', 'ability': 'Headbanger Icon'},
   {'level': 'Level 20', 'ability': 'No Control Icon'}]},
 {'build_name': 'Ez-Thro Dynamite Build',
  'category': 'Situational',
  'talents': [{'level': 'Level 1', 'ability': 'Journeyman Cooking Icon'},
   {'level': 'Level 4', 'ability': "Hogger's Joggers Icon"},
   {'level': 'Level 7', 'ability': 'Dense Blasting Powder Icon'},
   {'level': 'Level 10', 'ability': 'Shockwave Icon'},
   {'level': 'Level 13', 'ability': 'Pummel Icon'},
   {'level': 'Level 16', 'ability': 'Kablooie! Icon'},
   {'level': 'Level 20', 'ability': 'No Control Icon'}]},
 {'build_name': 'ARAM Build',
  'category': 'ARAM',
  'talents': [{'level': 'Level 1', 'ability': 'Journeyman Cooking Icon'},
   {'level': 'Level 4', 'ability': "Hogger's Joggers Icon"},
   {'level': 'Level 7', 'ability': 'Dense Blasting Powder Icon'},
   {'level': 'Level 10', 'ability': 'Shockwave Icon'},
   {'level': 'Level 13', 'ability': 'Pummel Icon'},
   {'level': 'Level 16', 'ability': 'Kablooie! Icon'},
   {'level': 'Level 20', 'ability': 'No Control Icon'}]}]
```

Comment: Thank you sir, your code works like a charm when replacing that snippet! I can see what you're getting at